# What are the coordinates of the vertices of a regular tetrahedron, relative to its centroid?

Tags: geometry, 3d

I am trying to draw an equilateral/regular tetrahedron in Processing (subset of Java), so I have to define 4 triangles that meet at the 4 vertices. I have been able to find the coordinates for the vertices assuming 1 of the vertices is at the origin.

However, the tetrahedron rotates, and I would like its rotation to be about its centroid. This where I get stuck, I need to define the 4 planes of the tetrahedron when the centroid is at the origin.

I hope my question is clear. :/ Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Formulas_for_a_regular_tetrahedron), if the origin is at the centre, then you can take the vertices to be

$$(\pm 1, 0, -1/\sqrt{2}),\,\,\,\,\, (0, \pm 1, 1/\sqrt{2}).$$

The article does also give some alternatives such as $(1, 1, 1, ), (1, -1, -1), \dots $ which might be easier to work with.

Comment: Thanks! I have another question: How are the vertices related to edge-length? It says these coordinates are for a tetrahedron of length 2 – so does that mean I replace the sqrt(2) with sqrt(edge)?

Comment: It means that the first set of coordinates in the answer give an edge length of 2. For a tetrahedron with edge length 1, just divide all the above coordinates by 2, etc (including the $\pm 1$ coordinates).

Answer (score 20):

I happened to have a suitable image on my laptop (for my freshman course), so I couldn't resist
[image: methane molecule]

It is supposed to be a methane molecule as opposed to a tetrahedron, so think of the hydrogen atoms (green) as vertices of the tetrahedron. As you see, this is the second arrangement
in Old John's (+1) answer. One vertex is at the point $(1,1,1)$ and the other three at the points $(\pm1,\pm1,\pm1)$ with **exactly** two minus signs occuring. In other words, four selected corners of a cube.

I second Old John's opinion that this is very well suited for 3D-rotations, because you surely know the effect of a rotation on the cube...

Comment: Very nice! I have never mastered the art of creating nice images, unfortunately.